# 'inversion' tactic for ssreflect: What should I use?

Tags: ssreflect

Using ssreflect, I fell in love with its style of actively managing binders into and from the goal. However, I had problems with searching for what I want from its documentation.

In particular, I cannot find the ssreflect tactic for the `inversion` tactic.

I understand that I can very well use `inversion` tactic.
Yet, it follows the traditional coq style in using binders, where I am having hard time specifying correct names per branch as it is 'hidden' from the multiple goal view.
Meanwhile, ssreflect tactics always discharge the binders into the goal, so I could bind names to those alike `move`.

For instance, by applying inversion on `Forall2 R l m`, I get

```
x0: A
y0: B
l0: list A
l': list B
H3: R x y
H5: Forall2 R l m
H0: x0 = x
H1: l0 = l
H2: y0 = y
H4: l' = m
```

which are the names I do not like, and tracking and specifying those would be painful as the bindings are hidden behind the second branch (first branch is merely `l = m = []`).

What can I use if I want to invert an inductive type, in ssreflect style? Can `elim` be used for some kind of inversion?

Comment: When I was looking for the same question I found it on google https://sympa.inria.fr/sympa/arc/ssreflect/2014-10/msg00007.html, even though it is old.

Comment: @TiagoCampos Thank you!!! The link answers the question in full extent!